# C# final block is not executing when exception thrown from catch

Tags: try-catch, finally

When I put `SecondMain()` inside the try blcok the final block inside `secondMain()` is executing. But when I put it outside it's not executing. Why isn't it executing?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            SecondMain(args); //try putting 
            Console.WriteLine("try 1"); 
            throw new Exception("Just fail me");              
        }            
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("finally");
        }

    }


    static void SecondMain(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            throw new StackOverflowException();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("catch");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("finally");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it doesnt matter whether the SecondMain() method is called from outside or inside the try block.

The program always crashes because you dont handle the Exceptions and the MainExceptionHandler from the .Net Environment has to take care of this. He gets an unhandled exception and quits your program.

Try this and now i think your code behaves like expected.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    try
    {
        SecondMain(args); //try putting 
        Console.WriteLine("try 1"); 
        throw new Exception("Just fail me");              
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Caught");
    }      
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("finally");
    }

}


static void SecondMain(string[] args)
{

    try
    {
        throw new StackOverflowException();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("catch");
        //throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("finally");
    }

}
```

I hope this is the answer you were looking for.